# What are the identifying characteristics of a Jellyfish?

Tags: zoology, species, species-identification

I was walking down the beach today (Wollongong Australia, near Sydney) and saw this Jellyfish washed up on the beach. 
[image]

Then I saw another. 
[image]

I wanted to work out what type it was but didn't know where to start.  I'm looking for a process to determine the category of Jellyfish this is.

I've had a look at [this chart](http://www.stingeradvisor.com/files/jellyfish%20of%20GBR%20ID.jpg):
[image]

which tells me it is probably a ***Catastylus Mosaicus*** (Blubber fish).

I've also looked at [this chart](http://www.mcsuk.org/downloads/wildlife/jellyfishform.jpg):
[image]

which tells me it is probably a Rhizostoma Octopus - ***Barrel or Root Mouth JellyFish*** (name only - still a jellyfish).

The biggest identifying characteristic seems to be the eight legs. (Clearly a jelly fish - but still a very confusing trait).

My question is: **What are the identifying characteristics of a Jellyfish?**

Comment: Did you do any research at all about [jellyfish](http://ocean.si.edu/jellyfish-and-comb-jellies)? What did you find? What was confusing?

Comment: @anongoodnurse I am wondering if they are using "category" in the colloquial sense and what they really mean is that they are interested in finding out how you can look at a jellyfish and visually identify its species.

Comment: @AMR - I think you're right, but it's kind of broad. Intro to jelly fish is better approached on one's own, and this site can help with the difficulties. Just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. I've added some comments on my own personal investigation.

Comment: Blubber fish is far more likely. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhizostoma_pulmo and http://oceanaddicts.ie/blog/rhizostoma-octopus-barrel-jellyfish

Comment: Thanks @AMR - can you expand that into an answer?

Comment: On that @AMR - the linked article implies it is not common in the Pacific ocean (although my feeling is the article is incorrect) could you comment on that?

Comment: All I was showing you was that the Barrell or Root Mouth doesn't appear to be endemic to your area, so it is more likely your first choice, the Catastylus Mosaicus (Blubber fish).